# Trying to prevent session timeout due to inactivity

Tags: firefox, session, timeout

I am a student and need to be logged into www.taskstream.com for long periods of time. But it automatically logs me out if I have been inactive for more than 90 minutes. How do I stop this from happening? I use Firefox and have tried browser extensions like Session Keeper and others but nothing works. I have also tried greasemonkey scripts but nothing has worked. But then again, I am new to userscripts and am probably doing something wrong. Once I log in, it takes me to https://www.taskstream.com/Main/main_frame.asp and this is the site I need to stay logged into. I have noticed that when I click around in the site, the url never changes.

Comment: If everyone did that, they would need to increase the subscription prices since it would generate an unneeded load on the servers.  They probably intentionally found ways to block the tools that you tried.  I can see some ways around it but it would be unethical to suggest them.

Comment: Web sites do this on purpose, not just to be ornery. It frees up bandwidth for those who are actually using the site.

Comment: Because session is controlled server side, if their implementation is strong and secure, you will not be able to do this from the browser, period. Most session mechanisms do rely on cookies to identify session and authentication identity, so you may be able to manipulate it somewhat, but expiration occurs server side, so no amount of cookie hackery will allow you to just resume a session. you would have to focus on how to send the cookie to them periodically to update its expiration time server-side, and update your cookies expiration time as well. unless they have a session fixation vuln.